# Jenkins plugin descriptor with nested parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, descriptor, jelly

I'm writing descriptors for somebody else's pipeline steps jenkins plugin.  Most steps are straight forward, e.g.

```
mySimpleStep(param1: value1, param2: value2)
```

However one of the steps requires a parameter, which is a map of two other values, so the actual call syntax is the following:

```
myOtherStep(param1: value1, param2: [sub1: value2, sub2: value3])
```

I can't fathom how to specify the parameters in the `config.jelly` file for the step and/or update the actual `Step` class so that the call syntax is created correctly. How can I do that?

(`param2` class does have its own `@DataBoundConstructor` if it matter)

Do note that this is somebody else's plugin, I am in no position to change the actual plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After almost giving up, I stumbled upon the answer while looking at the source code of Microsoft Azure Storage plugin.  Here are the steps I needed to do.

1. Ensure that the class of `param2` implements `Step` and add `Description` inner class to it. It also needs to have a `@DataBoundConstructor`
2. Create a separate descriptor directory for the class in resources with its own `config.jelly` and `help-*.html` files
3. Change the config.jelly of `myOtherStep` to have something like this:

   ```
   <f:section title="General">
       <f:entry field="value1" title="First param" description="Simple parameter">
           <f:textbox/>
       </f:entry>

       <f:property field="value2">
           <st:include page="config.jelly"/>
       </f:property>

   </f:section>
   ```

Now the `config.jelly` class for the complex parameter will be included - and everything works as expected.